# Passing form input dynamically to action from erb

Tags: ruby, forms, sinatra, erb

I'm building a Sintatra app that will allow me to pass information between the erb files and the main app then vice versa allowing the user to fill out multiple forms and manipulating the url to get them to the correct form I need them at.

Form 1 exists at /venue/checkin. I pass the venue to the erb file to ask their name and table

```
<form action='<%= @venue %>/<%= @table %>/attempt' method='post' class="form-horizontal">

    <input class="span12" type="text" name='firstname' placeholder="Firstname" autofocus>

    <input class="span12" type="text" name='username' placeholder="Lastname">

    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">Table #</span>
        <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" name='<%= @table %>' placeholder="4">
        </div>

        <input class="btn btn-large btn-info" type='submit' value='Order'>
</form>
```

I want to post to existing venue name and table the user provides in the form directing us back to app.rb

```
get '/:venue/:table/order' do
  erb :order
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add or update information via HTTP, it's helpful *not* to redirect at the end, because you have to use a status code for redirection, when the client really wants a status code that tells it whether the operation was a success.

So that you can both be happy, why not supply the same "order" route as both a GET and on a successful POST? e.g.

```
get "/:venue/:table/order" do
  # get info from storage
  erb :order
end

post "/:venue/:table/order" do
  # get info from params and store it
  erb :order
end
```

The POST route will [send back a 200 (or 201)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_http_status_codes#2xx_Success) *and* the stuff you want to show. If the client ever requests to see the order again, they can use the route with a GET request.

If the only information about /venue/table/ is in fact an order then I'd drop "order" from the route, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you cannot dynamically post to a route when you are collecting the information in the form(correct me if i'm wrong). I'm instead sending the POST to a generic page and utilizing the information I get in the form like so:

```
<form action='/orders/drinks' method='post' class="form-horizontal">

<input class="span12" type="text" name='firstname' placeholder="Firstname" autofocus>

<input class="span12" type="text" name='lastname' placeholder="Lastname">

<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on">Table #</span>
    <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" name='table' placeholder="4">
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-large btn-info" type='submit' value='Order'>
```

which **POSTs** back to **app.rb**

```
post '/orders/drinks' do
  if session[:venue]
    @order = Order.new
    session[:lastname] = params['lastname']
    session[:firstname] = params['firstname']
    session[:table] = params['table']
    erb :"orders/drinks"
  else
    erb "There has been an error saving your checkin information. Please try again later."
  end
end
```

Then redirect back to the **GET** for the next form:

```
get '/orders/drinks' do
  if session[:lastname]
    erb :"orders/drinks"
  else
    erb "There was an error saving your checkin information"
  end
end
```